# Pandas Sales Analysis Help - ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently running a sales analysis on an excel file with roughly 500 transactions. I have a category called "Sale Price" which should be read in as a float. Pandas read in the dtype as an object, and when trying to change the dtype to a float using:

```
df['Sale Price'].fillna(0).astype(float)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

I've tried mixing in various command combinations such as:

```
df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['Sale Price'], errors='coerce').isnull()]
```

and:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Sale Price']).astype(int)
```

in order to convert the column to a float, but now I'm thinking the issue is in how the data is being read in. I used the basic:

```
df = pd.read_excel('...')
```

Hopefully someone can help clarify where the issue is coming from as I've been stuck for awhile. Thank you!

Comment: tackle it at the source and define it as an NA value: `pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', na_values='')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your empty strings with 0 before changing it to float:

```
df["Sale Price"] = df["Sale Price"].astype(str).str.strip().replace("",0).astype(float)
```

Comment: you should also fill the na's with zero before converting to float. Unless that is handled in the conversion?

Comment: I appreciate the prompt response! However, when I run the code snippet here, it still gives the same error. I do have empty values in my excel sheet as that's how the spacing worked out, which seems to be the issue!

Comment: @The_Bandit - Can you try my edited answer? Using `strip()` removes all extra spaces before replacing with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have a empty string somewhere in your sale price. As indicated by the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

To fix this first run:

```
df['Sale Price'] = df['Sale Price'].where(df['Sale Price'] != '', 0)
```

This will replace any empty strings with zero

Comment: This ran, but when I add my code to change the dtype right after the code you provide here, it kicked the same error and I'm stuck as to why it did that. Thank you for the response!

Comment: @The_Bandit I can see from the other answer that you already got it working but the change would essentially be the same :) Happy coding!